# empty listbox return values with python 3.7 tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

why is this listbox not returning my selection? I added the returnSelected() function with a button thinking that it needed to be triggered. My goal is to create as simple a possible function that a user can select a reduced list, and I am clearly not understanding the tkinter flow.

```py
import tkinter
def listboxinput3():
    # <ListboxSelect> callback function and current selection
    def cb(event):
        label['text'] = str(event) + '\n' + str(lb.curselection())

    def returnSelected():
        myselection = [my_list[k] for k in lb.curselection()]
        print(myselection )

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Parameter Selection')
    root.geometry('200x600')
    my_list = dir(tkinter)
    var = tkinter.StringVar(value=my_list)

    label = tkinter.Label(root)
    label.grid()
    btnGet = tkinter.Button(root,text="Get Selection",command=returnSelected)
    btnGet.grid()
    lb = tkinter.Listbox(root, listvariable=var, selectmode='extended')
    lb.grid()
    lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', cb)
    #tkinter.Button(root, text="Show Selected", command=returnSelected).pack()
    selected_text_list = [lb.get(i) for i in lb.curselection()]
    root.mainloop()
    return selected_text_list

selected_text_list = listboxinput3()
```

Thanks

Comment: it seems you don't know how GUI works - you create `selected_text_list` before `mainloop` which starts program, display windows, gets your clicks and run `cb`, etc. - so you create this list before you even see window and select item. You have to create it inside function `cb` or `returnSelected` which is executed after you select item.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't know how GUI works. You create `selected_text_list` before `mainloop()` which starts program, displays window, gets your click, runs `cb` and `returnSelected`, etc. - so you create this list before you even see window and select item.

You have to create it inside function `cb` or `returnSelected` which is executed after you select item. And it will need `global selected_text_list` to assing it to external variable because `button` can't get it and assing it to external variable.

```
import tkinter

def listboxinput3():
    # <ListboxSelect> callback function and current selection

    def cb(event):
        label['text'] = str(event) + '\n' + str(lb.curselection())

    def returnSelected():
        global selected_text_list
       
        selected_text_list = [my_list[k] for k in lb.curselection()]
        
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Parameter Selection')
    root.geometry('200x600')
    
    my_list = dir(tkinter)
    var = tkinter.StringVar(value=my_list)

    label = tkinter.Label(root)
    label.grid()
    
    btnGet = tkinter.Button(root, text="Get Selection", command=returnSelected)
    btnGet.grid()
    
    lb = tkinter.Listbox(root, listvariable=var, selectmode='extended')
    lb.grid()
    lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', cb)
    
    #tkinter.Button(root, text="Show Selected", command=returnSelected).pack()
    # selected_text_list = [lb.get(i) for i in lb.curselection()]  # useless - it is executed before you even see window
    
    # display window, run function assigned to button when you click, etc.
    root.mainloop()

    return selected_text_list

selected_text_list = listboxinput3()
print(selected_text_list)
```

Comment: Excellent solution, and you are correct, I do not understand how GUI works, but thankfully you do! Thanks.